# Instead of using for loop, how do I make a loop where you tell it the amount of times you want it to loop?

Tags: java, loops

How would I create a loop where it has a condition, but in addition you can decide how many times you want it to loop. I know that the for loop does this, but what if I want a specific integer to determine how many times it will loop?

Example

```
//for loop below
  for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
       {

       }
```

Instead of doing the for loop (above), is there a way to choose a specific number of times you want it to loop, so that you can enter an integer variable in a properly which will tell it how many times you want it to loop?

Comment: Any loop can do that, you just have to use it properly.

Comment: Using a `for` loop the way you've done it is the normal way to do this.  You can replace `10` with a variable.  There isn't a special syntax to say "do this N times".  I can't think of any language that has a special syntax like this, except for COBOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few choices. The simplest is to replace `10` with a variable,

```
int length = 10;
for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
```

Alternatively, you could use a `while` loop,

```
int length = 10;
int x = 0;
while (x < length) {
 // ...
 x++;
}
```

Or a `do {} while` like

```
int length = 10;
int x = 0;
do {
 // ...
} while (x++ < length);
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that a do-while loop runs once before checking the specified condition.

Answer (score 2):

Every loop can be made to satisfy your constraints. A `while` loop might be most apt one in this case.

```
int count;
while (count-- != 0) {
    //statements
}
```

Will execute the loop body `count` number of times.

Comment: This actually won't compile since count-- does not evaluate to a boolean.  while (0 != count--)

Comment: @kharyam True. I assumed that this would result in the same outcome as in C++. Modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int amount = 50;

for(int x = 0; x < amount; x++) {
   // This will loop 50 times.
}
```

The integer after `x <` is the amount of times that it will loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using a loop, you can use Java 8 features :

```
IntStream.range(0,n).forEach(i -> {
    //someCode
});
```

This will run a block of code `n` times.

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
 System.out.println("enter amount of time you want the loop to run");
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
int amount=scanner.nextInt();
for(int i=1;i<=amount;i++){
System.out.println("Hii");
}
```

This program will ask you how may times you want to execute the loop.